# Create diferent childs struct that expand a function of a parent struct, and pass the child object in another function. C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I'm creating diferent Child Structs with a diferent implementation of a function, starting with a base Parent function.

I want a general reference to call the function of a Child in another struct as a pointer.
Then change to another child struct and call the function of the new child.

```
struct State{
   virtual void Update(){
   }
};


struct IdleState : State{
    void Update (bool* var){
        //some code
    }
};

struct StateMachine{
    State* currentState;
    void Initialize(State* newState){
        currentState = newState;
    }
    void Update(){
        currentState.Update();
    }
};
```

Comment: Well the main problem seems to be that your parent function has no parameters, but your child function has a bool pointer parameter. The child function has no relation to the parent function because of this. Can you change your functions so that they have the same parameters?

Comment: Of course the other problem is that if you have a pointer you should use `->` to call a member function, not `.`.

Comment: `currentState.Update()` i impossible, it should have `->`. and virtual function doesn't have an argument here

Comment: Add `override` keyword if functions in a derived class are intended to override a base class function – in this specific case (`void update(bool* var) override`) it would lead to a compilation error as it actually doesn't override due to parameter mismatch.

Comment: `StateMachine::initialize` function looks to me as if it rather should be a constructor (though specific use case might indeed rather require a separate function – but in this case a constructor lacks initialising `currentState` to `nullptr` to avoid an indeterminate state until `initialize` function is called – or more modern: initialise `currentState` directly (`State* currentState = nullptr;`).

Comment: A bit in doubt about your design in general. Typically (finite) state machine implementations are aware about the states they have, and they have a dedicated initial state. Might rather look similar to [this approach](https://godbolt.org/z/eadeGr7sc). If you try to create a general library then I'd stick with above but provide a `protected` interface for initialisation and selection of a follow-up state. Possibly template, too, to cover differing event types (which might be structs including parameters to avoid arbitrary complex variadic templates).

Comment: General advice: always use the `override` keyword when you want to override a virtual function, and always [enable compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) so that the compiler yells at you when you forget to do so.